# Issue while executing jar file to fetch tweets

Tags: java, cmd, jar, maven-2, maven-plugin

I have created maven project to fetch Tweets and storing in Kafka topic and I am trying to execute the project on the command line. 
First I added Main-class to MANIFEST.MF file. also added following code to the pom.xml file:

```
     <build>
                    <plugins>
                             <plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <version>2.2</version>
                            </plugin>

                            <plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <version>2.16</version>
                                    <configuration>
                                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                                    </configuration>
                            </plugin>

                            <plugin>
                                                    <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.4</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <archive>
                                            <manifest>
                                                    <mainClass>twitter.producerkafka</mainClass>
                                            </manifest>
                                    </archive>
                            </configuration>
                            </plugin>
                    </plugins>
    </build>
```

Then I created **twitter-streaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** file using the following command:

```
mvn clean package
```

The twitter-streaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is created in target folder of the project.

After that I tried to execute this .jar file using the following command:

```
[root@sandbox target]# jar -cvfm twitter-streaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar MANIFEST.MF twitter.producerkafka
```

Following is the error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: MANIFEST.MF (No such file or directory)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)
>           at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:175)
>           at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)

Also tried to execute the following command:

```
java -jar twitter-streaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Error:

> no main manifest attribute, in twitter-streaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: I don't get it. You use Maven to generate a jar file, but you then discard this jar file and create a new one, with the same name, using the jar command. Why? And why do you add the main class to the manifest by yourself, if you then ask Maven to add it for you?

Comment: Your main class is named `producerkafka`?

Comment: while executing twitter-streaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar file I was getting error **no main manifest attribute**  so using this command `jar -cvfm twitter-streaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar MANIFEST.MF twitter.producerkafka` I was trying to add MANIFEST . @JBNizet

Comment: `producerkafka` is Main class.
@RC.